# Is there a way to store Get-ChildItem object in variable

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to do next:

```
$a = $(Get-ChildItem -Path path | Select-Object -Property creationtime, name, size )
$a.Name
$a.CreationTime
$.Size
```

I am getting an error.

When I select single attribute - no problem.

Is there a way to select whole object into variable `$a`?

Comment: _I am getting an error._ And __what__ is your error? Why do you don't post it?

Answer (score 2):

There are some approaches thinkable:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -OutVariable ChildItems
$ChildItems.creationtime
```

Or you can use simply this:

```
$ChildItems = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp 
$ChildItems.creationtime
```

You should take a little time and learn the basics of Powershell.

Comment: hello Olaf, thank for recommendation. Can you recommend any book which concentrates on scripting rather then 1 line administrative tasks?

Comment: It depends a little bit on your native language I think. For English speakers I've been told that the books from Don Jones used to be very good. So [Learn Windows Powershell in a Month of Lunches](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-windows-powershell-in-a-month-of-lunches-second-edition) or [Powershell Deep Dives](https://www.manning.com/books/powershell-deep-dives). Bruse Payette wrote another good book [Windows PowerShell in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/windows-powershell-in-action-third-edition).